# how to install AWS CLI on windows server CORE ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I am looking to install the AWS CLI on a windows server core EC2 instance, as per the [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-windows.html) , The AWS CLI should be installed with `msiexec.exe /i https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.msi`. The problem with this, is that it will attempt to bring up a GUI - Windows server core does not have any GUI, and therefore we cannot interact with it. I have tried /quiet and other such commands, but the terminal simply gives no response.

How can I install the AWS CLI on a windows server core EC2 instance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install AWS CLI on windows server CORE ec2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70105795/install-aws-cli-on-windows-server-core-ec2-instance)

Answer (score 1):

Try a "quiet install":

`msiexec.exe /i https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.msi /qn`

Comment: Running this command seems to give no output, it does not do anything.

Comment: That's why it's called "quiet" ;)  It *should*, however, install the product.  You can also run `msiexec /?`  (from a Windows GUI) to see other options.  Including logging options.