# Install AWS CLI on Windows Server CORE EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I am looking to install the AWS CLI on a Windows Server Core EC2 instance. As per the Documentation, the AWS CLI should be installed with `msiexec.exe /i https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.msi`.

The problem with this, is that it will attempt to bring up a GUI - Windows server core does not have any GUI, and therefore we cannot interact with it. I have tried `/quiet` and other such commands, but the terminal simply gives no response.

How can I install the AWS CLI on a Windows Server Core EC2 instance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to install AWS CLI on windows server CORE ec2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68659448/how-to-install-aws-cli-on-windows-server-core-ec2-instance)

Answer (score 0):

Install the AWS Command Line Interface (CLI)

AWS Command Line Interface (CLI) Silent Install (MSI)

1. Navigate to: https://aws.amazon.com/cli/
2. Download the AWSCLIV2.msi to a folder created at (C:\Downloads)
3. Open an Elevated Command Prompt by Right-Clicking on Command Prompt and select Run as Administrator
4. Navigate to the C:\Downloads folder
5. Enter the following command: MsiExec.exe /i AWSCLIV2.msi /qn
6. Press Enter

After a few moments you will find AWS Command Line Interface (CLI) entries in the Installation Directory and Programs and Features in the Control Panel.

[aws](/questions/tagged/aws)   [ec2](/questions/tagged/ec2)

Answer (score -1):

you can follow the step

it will be help you to install AWS CLI you can open this below link

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html

1. you can install cli
2. and run command in terminal ➡　aws configure

   ```
   $ aws configure
   AWS Access Key ID [None]: AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
   AWS Secret Access Key [None]: wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
   Default region name [None]: us-west-2
   Default output format [None]: json
   ```

insert your information in above like this

hope it will help for you...

[amazonwebservices](/questions/tagged/amazonwebservices)  [aws](/questions/tagged/aws)   [ec2](/questions/tagged/ec2)

Comment: That does not answer the question of how to install the AWS CLI on Windows Server Core.